# Passing information from UEFI to the OS

Tags: c, windows, memory-management, bios, uefi

I am familiar with BIOS int 15 - E820 function, where you could choose a **fixed** physical location, put there whatever you wanted, the OS would not overwrite it, and you could just access that fixed memory address (may map it to a virtual pointer first etc).

But in the UEFI case, as much as I am aware, there is no memory area reserved for the user, so I couldn't rely on allocating a buffer at a specific memory address (if that's even possible?), therefore I have to use a UEFI memory memory function - which returns a pointer that is **not** fixed.

So my questions are -

1. Is it possible to allocate a buffer that will not be overwritten once the OS goes up?
2. How is it possible to pass the OS the pointer of the allocated buffer, so I could access it from the OS (again, since allocation, hopefully given that the buffer itself is not overwritten, is not in a fixed location).

Thank you!

Comment: There's no memory area reserved for the user with with INT 15h, AX=E820h either. It just returns a list of used regions of memory. You can replace it with your own routine that provides a modified list so an OS using this function won't use some region of memory. Maybe you could do the same with the equivalent UEFI function `GetMemoryMap`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes. Allocate memory memory of a non-reclaimable type, such as `EfiRuntimeServicesData`.
2. The mechanism UEFI uses is called *configuration tables*.

**Note:** `EfiPersistentMemory` is something completely different.

Configuration tables are installed by calling `InstallConfigurationTable` during boot services, with the two parameters being a GUID and a pointer to the physical address of the data structure you want to pass. This pair is then linked into an array pointed to by the UEFI System Table.

How you extract that information in Windows, I do not know. In Linux, the UEFI system table is globally accessible in kernel space (`efi->systab`), so the pointer can be extracted from there.